# Do clouds of dark matter cool and contract?

Tags: cosmology, dark-matter, wimps

If dark matter participates in the weak interaction, clouds could cool via thermal neutrino radiation...?

And even if does not participate in the weak interaction, clouds should contract via evaporation cooling.

Can anyone point me to papers on this? Is it possible to derive boundaries on the weak interaction cross section of dark matter from such considerations?

Comment: here is the standard cosmology model http://www.cosmotography.com/images/galaxy_formation_and_evolution.html